# Get the positions of a certain column in a data frame in ascending order in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the positions of the values in the second column of the dataframe below in ascending order but only for rows where the value of the first column is 0. Any idea how I could do this with the order function or anything else in R? My data frame is as follows:

```
par <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
par1 <- c(0.10,0.3,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.48,0.48,0.5)
p <- data.frame(par,par1)
```

Comment: What is your expected output in the example you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `which` to get the positions of the rows where `p$par == 0`, and then use `order` to reorder the vector based on ascending order.

```r
which(p$par == 0)[order(p$par1[p$par == 0])]
# [1] 1 2 5 8 3
```

Comment: The expected output is 1 2 5 8 3

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are after `which()` that returns the index of the TRUE values, and `sort()` which pull arrange them in ascending order.

```r
sort(which(p$par == 0))

#[1] 1 2 3 5 8
```

This gives you the row numbers where `par == 0` which you can use as desired.